# ciscoconfparse unable to import python3.7 win10

Tags: python, ciscoconfparse

Any new solution for this. I am unable to from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
I tried several versions of ciscoconfparse in python3  usin gpowershell in windows10.

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ciscoconfparse import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\ciscoconfparse.py", line 4018

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I still have not found a version that will let me import the module.
I browsed through several links here..but did not find an answer. The closest issue to mine is:
 [ciscoconfparse in Python 3.4 module doesn't import correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997149/ciscoconfparse-in-python-3-4-module-doesnt-import-correctly)
but not answer.

Any new info?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/issues/117 states there is something broken in 3.7 but that 3.6 should work

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the bug where Win10 and Python 3.7.0 cause problems.

FWIW, if you completely uninstall Python 3.7.0 (including manually deleting your Windows installation directory tree), then install Python 3.7.1, you should not have this problem with Windows 10.